# What is the smallest value for this expression? (explanation needed)

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the smallest value for the expression, $a^2+b^2+ab-a-2b$?

Please explain this.

Comment: For *what* equation?  $a^2+b^2+ab-a-2b, -1$ doesn't seem to be an equation.

Comment: I think its $....-1=0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar ???????

Comment: If it weren't for the weird ", -1" which I truly do not understand what is meant by, I would have thought this meant what is the smallest value for the *expression* (NOT an equation) $a^2 + b^2 + ab - a - 2b$.

Comment: Ya thinking the same

Comment: $-1$ is the minimum value of $a^2 + b^2 + ab - a - 2b$ for real $a,b$

Answer (score 2):

You might try expanding $$\tfrac14(a+2b-2)^2+\tfrac34 a^2 - 1$$
and then consider why $a=0, b=1$ gives a minimum

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you have the function $$f=a^2+b^2+ab-a-2b$$ Compute its derivatives $$f'_a=2 a+b-1$$ $$f'_b=2 b+a-2$$ You search for an extremum; if it exists, at a point $f'_a=f'_b=0$. So two equations for two unknowns.

I am sure that you can take it from here.